# Site Redirects to Subdomain if "www." is not typed in URL

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, domain, wordpress, reverse-proxy

I am running a WordPress site on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.16.11-051611-generic x86_64), we'll call it myDomain.com.

I have a .NET Core app deployed on the **same server** with the domain name like: myApp.myDomain.com that runs on port **5003**.

If you do not have [www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com) cached in your browser and you type in the address bar "myDomain.com", you get redirected to myApp.myDomain.com instead of [www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com).

I have made a ton of changes to the .htaccess file in WordPress and it did not fix the issue so I am thinking that it's my Apache .conf file for my .NET application (VirtualHost config for the app, myApp.myDomain.com):

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On


    ProxyPass / http://myDomainIP:5003/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://myDomainIP:5003/
    ServerName myApp.myDomain.com
    ServerAlias *.myApp.myDomain.com


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}myApp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}myApp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>


    ServerName myApp.myDomain.com

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/myCert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/myWildcardCert.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/myCertFile.crt
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}httpsmyApp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}httpsmyApp-access.log common


    ProxyPreserveHost On


    ProxyPass / http://myDomainIP:5003/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://myDomainIP:5003/
</VirtualHost>
```

VirtualHost config for the site myDomain.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName myDomain.com
ServerAlias www.myDomain.com
Redirect / https://www.myDomain.com/

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.myDomain.com


Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/myCert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/myWildcardCert.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/myCertFile.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Any thoughts on if this could be why this redirection happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explicitely check, what redirections happen (i.e. not only the outcome, but the steps on the way) and edit your question with the infos.